# isset($_COOKIE['cname']) not working on using php refresh header

Tags: php

On the first visit to my website, I redirect users to a welcome page using the following code.

```
// INDEX.PHP

include('backend-scripts/constants.php');

// set a cookie for the first website visit of the day.
if (isset($_COOKIE['firstVisit'])) {
    continue;
}
else {
    setcookie('firstVisit', 'no', time()+50, '/');

    header("Location: $baseURL/pages/welcome.php");
}
```

The else clause works perfectly and redirects to welcome.php. However in welcome.php when I want to redirect back to homepage, I do the following:

```
// WELCOME.PHP

include('backend-scripts/constants.php');

header("Refresh: 5;url=$baseURL");
```

and finally for the $baseURL:

```
// CONSTANTS.PHP

$serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$baseURL = "http://".$serverName.":13215";
```

But it does not redirect back to homepage and welcome.php keeps on refreshing.

My Guess: It probably gets successfully redirected to homepage but somehow finds $_COOKIE['firstVisit'] unset and comes back to welcome.php

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is that `continue` inside of a loop? If not, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Heya, post more code please, what is stored under $baseURL? try to echo it before sending header refresh. Name the files, what is where, because this code looks 'fine', but the problem is somewhere in other parts of code. + Yes remove continue.

Comment: Try extending the expiry time of the cookie.

Comment: I generally start debugging this type of this by putting a `var_dump($_COOKIE)` right before that `if()` statement, just so you can be sure of the cookie's state. Also as JM Verastigue stated - your cookie expires rather quickly. I would even try an expiry time that's like 5 hours from now just to be sure

Comment: 50 seconds is still 10 times more than 5 seconds of refresh time. Although the original cookie is intended to last for 24 hours, I shortened the time for development phase. But just to be sure let me retry with a longer duration.

Comment: `header("Refresh: 5;url=$baseURL")` – that is not a valid HTTP response header. You will most likely say _“but it works”_ now – but that is _only_ for the systems/browsers you have tested it with. It is __bound to fail__ somewhere in some environment, so don’t use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 // WELCOME.PHP

 include('backend-scripts/constants.php');
 global $baseURL;
 header("Refresh: 5;url=$baseURL");
```

and leaving the if block empty would also work fine

```
 if (isset($_COOKIE['firstVisit']))
 {

 }
```